# WPF: Quiz Application

Tags: wpf, windows, visual-studio, blend

I'd like to make a Quiz application, when initially run, a startup window is displayed that has information like; how many questions there are, how much are the total marks and passing marks and a button to start the quiz.

When the button is clicked, a new window opens for question 1. This window consists of a Label(Question), 3-4 radio buttons and a NEXT QUESTION button  (This button closes the current window and opens a new window for question 2). This happens until the last question.

Bear in mind that while this is happening the startup window does not close and with each new window it shows current obtained marks.

In the end The startup window show how many questions were answered wrong and display the Grade.

I can code everything except I can't figure out how to make the startup window Display the  current obtained marks during the quiz.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: This question seems too broad. Can you narrow down what specific programming problem you want the solution to?

Comment: i'm going to be using 'if else statement'. So where do I actually code in the main window that the current question is answered correctly so +1 in the marks obtained variable

Comment: I suggest you look more into WPF Data binding. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750612(v=vs.110).aspx